# Meteor - Publish/Subscribe to user data while not logged in

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've searched and read through pretty much all the questions relating to Meteor's pub/sub functionality but cant seem to find an answer that directly addresses my question.

I am learning Meteor and would like to create the following;

A user visits a page and is presented with an input box, they enter their username and if its a valid username I present them with the password input field.

The problem I seem to be having is that I cant access the Meteor.users collection unless I am logged in (the auto-publish and insecure packages have been removed).

So my question is 2 fold;

Is is possible to access the Meteor.users.find({username: 'value of input box'}) without being logged in?

If so, what do I need to do?

Here is how I have my code structured below;

**/server/publications.js:**

```
Meteor.publish("staff", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

**/lib/router.js:**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});


Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/', data: function() {return Meteor.subscribe('staff');} });
});
```

**/client/views/home/home.js:**

```
Template.home.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var guest = $("input#name");
  var staffMember = Meteor.users.findOne({username: $(guest).val()});
});
```

Unless I am logged in as any user, Meteor.users.find().fetch() always returns an empty array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are publishing all the Users to be visible on the client. That is not a very *secure* position to be in since all your user data will be visible on *all* the clients. The pragmatic way to solve the problem is to allow the user to see only a limited number of users, i.e. publish a different set of *users*, depending on the `userId`.

As @Hubert's answer below indicates, you also need to *subscribe* to the publication on the client to actually fetch the published accounts over.

---

You can do this checking for validity *securely* by creating a [Method call](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) on the server:

**/server/methods.js:**

```
Meteor.method({
    validUserName: function (userName) {
        check(userName, string);
        // You have access to Meteor.users here.
        // This assumes that mere existence of a user with the same username will
        // render the entered username invalid. If there are more checks you want to
        // make, they should be made here.
        return !!Meteor.users.find({username: userName});
    }
});
```

**/client/views/home/home.js:**

```
Template.home.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var guest = $("input#name");
  var userNameEntered = $(guest).val();

  Session.set('requestInProgress', true);

  Meteor.call('validUserName', function (isUserNameValid) {
       Session.set('requestInProgress', false);
       // ... take action here.
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i like your idea of making a method call. When I try your solution however I am getting undefined for the isValidUsername value when I enter a valid account name.

Comment: @user2209090 Ah, true, how silly of me. The call returns `undefined` on the client unless a call back is passed. Am updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're publishing all your user data to everyone, now you just need to subscibe to it:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('staff');
});
```

That said, make sure that in such subscription you publish only non-sensitive user data, as it will be visible to everyone. Ideally, create another subscription for that purpose and filter just the username via the `fields` param.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `autorun`? IMO, there are no reactive calls in the function so this computation will never be rerun. Is there something I am missing here? :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, like musically_ut said I dont think I will need to make this reactive but my question is where do I place the subscription code? In the router.js or the home.js file?

Comment: Anywhere on the client side (so, in any gile that is not in the /server folder). As for the deps, feel free not to use it in this case :-)

Comment: I actually got this working without the subscription/publication. In the Meteor.methods call i simply do the needed checks and set a Session.set({someProperty: true}) if the user is valid.